# PHP wont run multiple queries

Tags: php

This PHP script, is for "virtual companies" on my website. Its made so that, when a user sends credits/pixels to the company, it should be removed from the user and into the company's account.

The script is not returning any errors and sends the user to "/me" in the end, so i would think that the problem is that the queries is not being run.

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sendmoneyvirk'])) {

    $credits = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['credits']);
    $creditsnew = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $credits);        

    $pixels = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pixels']);
    $pixelnew = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $pixels);       


        $getUserinfo = mysql_query("SELECT activity_points, username, credits, online FROM users WHERE id = ".intval($_SESSION['user']['id']));
        while($userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getUserinfo)) {    
         $pixelsval = $userinfo['activity_points'];
         $creditsval = $userinfo['credits'];
        }


    if ($creditsnew > $creditsval) {
        header('Location: index.php?url=me&error=c1');
        exit;
    }

    if ($pixelsnew > $pixelsval) {
        header('Location: index.php?url=me&error=p1');
        exit;
    } 

    function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

      preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
      $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

      if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
        if($invert == FALSE) { 
          return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 
        else { 
          return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 
      } 
      elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
        return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
      } 
      return $text; 
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credits = credits - '".strip_tags_content($creditsnew)."' WHERE id = '$userid'")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE companies SET credits = credits + '".strip_tags_content($creditsnew)."' WHERE id = '$virkidnew'")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET activity_points = activity_points - '".strip_tags_content($pixelsnew)."' WHERE id = '$userid'")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE companies SET pixels = pixels + '".strip_tags_content($pixelsnew)."' WHERE id = '$virkidnew'")or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location: me');
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly - you should look at using [mysql PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as mysql_query is 'old and busted' ([read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php))

Seccondly, you can take a look at what is happening on mysql_query by using [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) - this will tell you how many rows you changed per UPDATE - if the answer is 0 for any / all of the queries then it is most likely because you have some problem with the query - i suggest grabbing the query and running in directly against the database (using [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net) or similar) to debug it.

Obviously this is just a code snippet, but it looks like $userid could be empty / not set - worth also looking at that.